# I built a todo list in React Native and compiled it to apk, but when I open the app on my phone it just shows "Welcome to React Native"

Tags: android, react-native

And there's no way to skip it. It says to shake the device to open the debug menu, but that doesn't work. Here's a screenshot from the app:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Mn7.jpg)

I have been searching the solution for hours now, but no luck. What can I do now?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without your actual code there's no way to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: OK, so I created a GitHub repository [link](https://github.com/Igol4/ToDo-List-app) and I uploaded only two files that I wrote by myself. There's also a bunch of other stuff in the folder that are created by expo and Android Studio trying to get the app compiled. I can upload that as well if needed.

Comment: It seems like it built the project with template code. Have you tried rebuilding the apk?

Comment: I tried rebuilding, but now the app just closes immediatelyafter opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by rebuilding the app with .\gradlew assembleRelease command